# using ProtectedSessionStorage in abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side

I would like to ask a question about how can I get values from the ProtectedSessionStorage, if I am using async methods from a abstract class.
The scenario is as follows:
I have a few model classes which all inherit from the abstract SQLQueryBuilder, to make use of some methods to setup Queries and execute them to save the models in the database.

Now the abstract should use the recent user (saved in the  ProtectedSessionStorage) to save it into a database field. For obvious reasons I can't inject the session or sessionhelper into the abstract.

My Question is, what is the best way for these model objects to have access to the session. Is there a need to inject those things into the models  (Like below) and do I then even have access to the sessionhelper or the sessionstorage?

```
public abstract class SqlQueryBuilder<T>
{
    [Inject] public Session.Sessionhelper sessionhelper { get; set; }
    [Inject] public ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage { get; set; }
     ...
  public asyn Task<int> foo(){
    //sessionhelper and sessionStorage are null
  }
}

public class Bar: SqlQueryBuilder<ProductionArticleModel>
{
    [Inject] public new Session.Sessionhelper sessionhelper { get; set; }
    [Inject] public new ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage { get; set; }
    public Bar()
    {
       //sessionhelper and _sessionstorage are null here too
    }
```

Bar gets called from the componentbases, which have access to the sessionhelper.

I hope I could make my issue clear enough and thanks in advance!